# How can these be proved?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Our college professor wrote two questions and just told us to think of them and how could they proved and what are they based on? So, here they are:

1. $\forall x \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]: \exists x(n)  \in (\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}) \cap [0,1]: \lim_{n \to \infty} x(n) = x$
2. $\forall x \in (\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}) \cap [0,1]: \exists x(n)  \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [0,1]: \lim_{n \to \infty} x(n) = x$

Tip: $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, which translates to $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}: \exists x(n) \in \mathbb{Q}: \lim_{n \to \infty} x(n) = x$.

Comment: Hint: this has nothing to do with group theory.

Comment: @DerekHolt ok thanks

Comment: How do you expect us to respond to you just dropping your homework here? Should we do your homework for you? Should we help you with specific parts of it, if so which ones? Have you tried anything? For now, why don't you follow your professors advice and think about them. Then come back with any specific questions you might have. That is going to be for more helpful for your own learning
Edit: the question was answered already, an oppertunity for learning was lost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question: you must prove there is a sequence of irrationals in $[0,1]$ converging to a given rational number $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Let's assume that $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{2}$. Take the sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ defined by
$$x_n = x + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{n+3}$$
You can prove that:

1. $x_n \in \mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ for all $n$, else $\sqrt{3}$ would be rational.
2. $x_n \in [0,1]$ since $x \leq \frac{1}{2}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{n+3} \leq \frac{1}{2}$

If $\frac{1}{2} \leq x \leq 1$, you can define a similar sequence easily.

For the second question: let $x$ be an irrational number in $[0,1]$. For example, say $x = 0.243515324241243847934124074017410471241641\cdots$. 
Define
$$\begin{align}x_1 &= 0\\
x_2 &= 0.2\\
x_3 &= 0.24\\
x_4 &= 0.243\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
x_{10} &= 0.243515324\\
&\;\;\vdots
\end{align}$$
i.e. $x_n$ is the truncation of the decimal represenation of $x$ to $n$ decimals. Try to prove yourself why this sequence has the properties you seek.